# stopMonitoringForRegion is not removing the region

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, core-location

My app successfully entering in this delegate method

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"didEnterRegion = %@", region.identifier);
[self.clm stopMonitoringForRegion:region];
}
```

but `stopMonitoringForRegion` is not removing the region, Why?

Comment: What does "is not removing the region" mean?

Comment: @matt It should stop monitoring and remove the region, but when I call [self.clm monitoredRegions] I can still see the region.

Comment: I don't see you calling it. How do I know when or where you call `monitoredRegions`? What I see is that you are telling the location manager to stop monitoring for this region. Well, then it _does_ stop monitoring for this region. (However, your call is a bit risky; you should not say `[self.clm stopMonitoringForRegion:region]`. You should say `[monitor stopMonitoringForRegion:region]`. That probably has nothing to do with it, but it's worth doing things correctly.)

Comment: @matt Thank you :)